# Type mismatch error with Nothing and Loop is not terminating

Tags: excel, vba

I am using vba macros to find a non-empty cell in a `some_col`, starting from row 1. When I find that, I want to assign that to `pword` and the value of cell in ajdacent column to `cword`. But it seems that on running this code, the loop is not terminating because even after finding a non-empty cell, its not ending. (Also, it is showing type mismatch error if I use `pword = Nothing`, and on the msdn website, they gave this as an option to use for empty string.)

Can anyone please tell what is wrong here?

```
Dim pword As String
Dim cword As String
Dim present_row As Long
pword = ""

Cells(1, some_col).Activate
MsgBox "Active cell: " & ActiveCell.Address

Do
    If Not ActiveCell.value = "" Then
         pword = ActiveCell.value
         cword = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).value
    End If
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
         present_row = ActiveCell.Row
Loop Until pword = ""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Is Nothing` statement only with object types, but `String` is not an object.

Change

```
Loop Until pword Is Nothing
```

to

```
Loop Until pword = ""
```

Comment: @simico can you please tell why the loop is not terminating and why debugger is pointing to `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate`?

Comment: + 1 @Downey: Put this line `pword = ""` just before `If Not ActiveCell.value = ""` Then and it will be ok